# Splunk Dashboard/ CSS - Unable to center on panels in a Dashboard row

Tags: css, splunk

I have a Splunk dashboard where one of the row's has 10 panels. However, the metrics on each panel is not centered:
[image]

This is the original CSS code on the dashboard:
[image]

I also tried this CSS code but changed into into 2 rows which I cannot have:

```
  <html>
    <style>
       #CSSPanel{
         width:0% !important;
       }
       #errorSinglePanel{
         width:25% !important;
       }
       #errorStatsPanel{
         width:30% !important;
       }
       #errorLineChartPanel{
         width:45% !important;
       }
     </style>
  </html>
```

[image]

Can you please help????

Comment: Normally Splunk "just does" the centering of a single value in its own panel. Have you tried removing/disabling the CSS you're tried adding, and see how it renders? Do you have trend lines, legends, etc enabled? What version of Splunk?

Comment: I tried this without any CSS formatting and it didn't work sadly. I am using version 9.0 pf Splunk btw.

Answer (score 0):

I plopped a few extra single value fields in a row (no custom CSS), and Splunk renders them all centered in their panels

[image: sample multi-entry single value panels in a row]